# Can I use ContentProviderOperation.Builder for an update operation with a reference to the current value

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider

I want to use the ContentProviderOperation.Builder methods to make an update that uses the current value to calculate the new value:

```
UPDATE table SET col1 = col1 + 1
```

Is such an update possible with ContentProviderOperation.Builder?